# Custom form on sitefinity backend page not working

Tags: backend, sitefinity

i have created a sitefinity back-end page, on it i have added a form and submit button, my problem is when i submit the page just reloads and does not even hit the break point in my back-end. I have inspected and it does not even generate the form markup.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadAdvertClicksReport", "Reports", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.From, new { @class = "sixteenpx" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From, null, new { @class = "form-control datepicker sixteenpx" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.To, new { @class = "sixteenpx" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.To, null, new { @class = "form-control datepicker sixteenpx" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Advert, new { @class = "sixteenpx" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Advert, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.PublishedAdverts, new { @class = "form-control sixteenpx border-0" })

    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="download" class="btn btn-primary sixteenpx">Download report</button>

}

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadAdvertClicksReport(AdvertClicksViewModel viewModel)
    {

        return Content(string.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The backend pages are asp.net web forms pages and as such they already have a form element at the top.

With this, you are basically trying to nest forms which is not possible.

That's why, for cases like this you need to use the @Html.BeginFormSitefinity helper method.

Example of how it is used: https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/blob/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Identity/Mvc/Views/LoginForm/LoginForm.LoginForm.cshtml

Comment: Is there anything else needed here? I am facing the same issue and using Html.BeginFormSitefinity in which it looks like it's generating a <div id="defaultForm"> but still having the issue as described above

Comment: under this div, it would generate a script tag with code inside that catches all submit click events and creates a form on the fly which is then submitted. Might want to put a debugger in chrome dev toolbar in this script and see what is happening